# @supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) not working in iOS 15 Safari

Tags: css, ios, safari

I'm trying to target iOS devices with CSS. The general advice is to use:

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
    ...
}
```

However, this does not seem to work with `iOS 15 Safari`. Is this true?

It looks like it is supposed to work from the [Apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_touch_callout) (last updated 2016), but a similar problem is [reported here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691021).

If this code does not work with `iOS 15`, what is the work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm `@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none)` still working fine on Safari iOS 15.4.1